# How to validate the name property of an element in XML file using javax xml validation

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have the following XML file:

```
<node name="FIXED_NAME">
  ...
</node>
```

Note that all elements in my XML are **node** (same name) and I can not change them for some reasons.
I am using java xml validator and xsd file for validation.
I want to validate that the **name property** for the **root node** must be **FIXED_NAME**.

How my xsd file should be?

Comment: As far as I am aware, and XSD file only defines the valid structure of nodes and properties in your document. It cannot say anything about the actual values in your document.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any solution to your problem, for these reasons:

XSD 1.0 identifies the type of a tag by matching the *hierarchy* of tags in the XML document against the element/type definitions in the XSD. In your case, there is no *hierarchy* of names (because all tag names are the same).

XSD 1.1 provides some extra flexibility via xs:alternative and xs:assert  - but they do not allow references to the parent axis.

For these reasons, I cannot think of any way to use the features of XML Schema to describe your XML.